# How can I make a tag run before others tags in google tag manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I Create a Tag in google tags manager and make it custom_html and bun a javascript function code inside  and i use the function inside another tag
But after I publish it it says fbq_custom() not define but when I open the gtm file i can see it there

I think the problem that with Priority, so how can i force the function to run before other tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. Like pushing an event that you're listening to after you define the function and on that event, you execute your custom HTML tag.

A more elegant solution would be using tag sequencing function in GTM:
[image]